# Adapt Stackpanel width to largest children (TextBlock) in XAML WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `StackPanel` that is as wide as its parent, inside an `ItemTemplate` of a `ListView`. I want to make it as wide as the largest children (several `TextBlock` here), which is not hardcoded, it depends on `TextBlock` content (`Name` or `LongTextAttributes` from the view model).

```
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LongTextAttributes}"/>    
</StackPanel>
```

How can I achieve this ?

Actual result:

[image: from]

Desired result:

[image]

Comment: Add `HorizontalAlignment="Left"`.

Comment: @Clemens That's what I want indeed !